# Make a service call while application is in background state

Tags: ios, swift

I have to hit server for every 30 seconds while application is in background state.if I had written code in applicationDidEnterBackground method it is getting called only once but I need to hit server continuously for every 30 seconds while app is in background.

Comment: You can’t. iOS apps don’t run in the background.

Comment: While you can fetch data in the background, you can't do it every 30 seconds (and you shouldn't even if you could - it is bad for battery life and network traffic). It is better for the server to send a push notification if there is new data or for the app to check the server when it comes to the foreground.

Comment: you mean we cannot hit server while app is in background state.....@matt

Comment: I have to send user location to server for every 30 seconds when an app is in background state ...... is it possible? .............@Paulw11

Comment: I have to send user location to server for every 30 seconds: Yes, You can do it. I was doing same thing https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1440569415 app. please refer it

Comment: I am working on it for the past one week but I couldn't do it.......Can u help me how to do this...... How could I hit server while app is in background state continuously.............Please help me ......thanks @iMHiteshSurani

Comment: If you have "always" location permission then you can get location updates while your app is in the background. You should edit your question to show the code you have tried and explain your problem more clearly

Comment: I am clear about my problem.....my problem is not getting location updates......I am getting location updates with  that updated location I have to hit server while app is in background state....@Paulw11

Comment: @KiranYechuri - it is quite straightforward; you send the update to your server in `didUpdateLocation`.

Comment: @Paulw11 - when app is in background state can we hit server continuously?

Comment: In theory you can do it every time you get a location update, which with GPS is about once per second. In reality you would only update the server every 30 updates or so as you suggest

Comment: @Paulw11- My concern is can u run service(post data to server) while application is in background state.......if you can run any service(post data to server) when application is in background state could u please provide me sample code......

Answer (score 2):

Please use [HSLocationManager](https://github.com/IMHitesh/HSLocationManager) for your requirement. I have achieved the same requirements in one of my project

> Location manager that allows getting background location updates every
> n seconds with desired location accuracy.
>
> **Advantage:**
>
> - OS will never kill our app if the location manager is currently
>   running.
> - Give periodically location update when it required(range is between 2 -
>   170 seconds (limited by max allowed background task time))
> - Customizable location accuracy and time period.
> - Low memory consumption(Singleton class)

**Default time to retrieve location is 30 sec and accuracy is 200.**

```
static let timeInternal = 30
static let accuracy = 200
```

## Update:

Yes, You can do it by writing API call in `didUpdateLocations` method.

```
func scheduledLocationManager(_ manager: HSLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   logh("Make API Call here...")
}
```

Comment: I want to post that data to my server is it possible with this pod?......@iMHitesh